# how to get the good performance in the big dom with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, conways-game-of-life

I wrote a little program in Javascript with jquery.

```
   var mlife = function (i, j, alive) {
    var face = '<div class="life" id="l_' + i + '_' + j + '"/>';
    var f = $(face);
    var ps = new Array();
    //var interval;
    this.draw=function() {
        if (alive) {
            f.addClass('l');
        } else {
            f.removeClass('l');
        }
    };
    this.aliveCheck=function() {
        var alivecount = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < ps.length; i++) {
            var el = $('#l_' + ps[i]);
            if (el.length > 0) {
                if (el.hasClass('l')) {
                    alivecount++;
                }
            }
        }
        if (alive) {
            if (alivecount < 2) {
                alive = false;
            } else if (alivecount == 2 || alivecount == 3) {
                alive = alive;
            } else if (alivecount > 3) {
                alive = false;
            }
        } else {
            if (alivecount == 3) {
                alive = true;
            }
        }
        //_draw();
    };
    this.getface = function () {
        return f;
    };
    function _init() {
        ps.push((i - 1) + '_' + (j - 1));
        ps.push((i - 1) + '_' + (j + 1));
        ps.push((i + 1) + '_' + (j - 1));
        ps.push((i + 1) + '_' + (j + 1));
        ps.push(i + '_' + (j - 1));
        ps.push(i + '_' + (j + 1));
        ps.push((i + 1) + '_' + j);
        ps.push((i - 1) + '_' + j);
        if (alive) {
            f.addClass('l'); 
        }

    };
    _init();
}
$(function () { 
    var html = "";
    var alive = false;
    var cells = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
            if (Math.random() > 0.90) {
                alive = true;
            } else {
                alive = false;
            }
            var l = new mlife(i, j, alive);

            cells.push(l);
            $('#show').append(l.getface()); 
        }
    }

    setInterval(allAliveCheck,1000);


    function allAliveCheck(){

        for(var i=0;i<cells.length;i++){
            cells[i].aliveCheck();
        }
        for(var i=0;i<cells.length;i++){
            cells[i].draw();
        }

    }







});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/chanjianyi/upgvzm78/1/

it's about the "game of life": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life

but I found it's very bad performance that control a lot of div.

So anybody have ideas to optimize my program?

Comment: How do you know it's performing badly?

Comment: @Richlewis It's freezing my browser lol. I would raise the interval

Comment: Code optimization questions are probably better off at http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Use the `<canvas>` element instead of `10000` divs o.O
On PC's that can handle it, you can make the application run faster by lowering the interval in `interval = setInterval(_aliveCheck, 1000);`

Comment: Also, something is going wrong in your algorithm, since the cells aren't properly dying. I'm getting a spreading bulk of life in your fiddle. The problem is that each individual cell checks it's neighbors, then updates it's "alive" status immediately. You should have all cells calculate their "next" state, _then_ let all cells change their state.

Comment: @Cerbrus  Thanks.　I will check the program. Means that I just need only one `setInterval` in my program?

Comment: Basically, yes. You want one interval that tells all cells to calculate their "next" state, and after that's done, tells all cells to change to their next state. That way, changes in the neighboring cells won't affect the current iteration.

Comment: @Cerbrus Thank you, I've modify the code, is it right now? http://jsfiddle.net/chanjianyi/upgvzm78/1/

Comment: Much better. It updates properly, now. Instead of using `hasClass` to check if a cell is alive, you might want to check for it's `alive` property, though. That'd be much faster.

Comment: @Cerbrus it seems that can't be. because cant get the object by id, just can get the element by $(id) then  using `hasClass`

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is slow. Ditch jQuery and it runs much faster. Here's an example.

```js
var mlife = function(i, j, alive) {
  // var face = '<div class="life" id="l_' + i + '_' + j + '"/>';
  var f = document.createElement('div');
  f.className = 'life';
  f.id = 'l_' + i + '_' + j;
  var ps = [];
  //var interval;
  this.draw = function() {
    if (alive) {
      f.classList.add('l');
    } else {
      f.classList.remove('l');
    }
  };
  this.aliveCheck = function() {
    var alivecount = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < ps.length; i++) {
      var el = document.getElementById('l_' + ps[i]);
      if (el) {
        if (el.classList.contains('l')) {
          alivecount++;
        }
      }
    }
    if (alive) {
      if (alivecount < 2) {
        alive = false;
      } else if (alivecount == 2 || alivecount == 3) {
        alive = alive;
      } else if (alivecount > 3) {
        alive = false;
      }
    } else {
      if (alivecount == 3) {
        alive = true;
      }
    }
    //_draw();
  };
  this.getface = function() {
    return f;
  };

  function _init() {
    ps.push((i - 1) + '_' + (j - 1));
    ps.push((i - 1) + '_' + (j + 1));
    ps.push((i + 1) + '_' + (j - 1));
    ps.push((i + 1) + '_' + (j + 1));
    ps.push(i + '_' + (j - 1));
    ps.push(i + '_' + (j + 1));
    ps.push((i + 1) + '_' + j);
    ps.push((i - 1) + '_' + j);
    if (alive) {
      f.classList.add('l');
    }

  };
  _init();
}


var html = "";
var alive = false;
var cells = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
    if (Math.random() > 0.90) {
      alive = true;
    } else {
      alive = false;
    }
    var l = new mlife(i, j, alive);

    cells.push(l);
    document.getElementById('show').appendChild(l.getface());
  }
}

setInterval(allAliveCheck, 1000);


function allAliveCheck() {

  for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    cells[i].aliveCheck();
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    cells[i].draw();
  }

}
```

```css
#show {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 0px solid red;
}
.life {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: black;
  float: left;
}
.l {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="show"></div>
</body>
```

Consider storing the playfield data as a simple array, rather than storing it in HTML elements. This way you can make arbitrary frontends to display the same data. A canvas or a simple preformatted block of text could give the same results visually; either one might perform better than a bunch of divs.

I'd suggest posting your code on codereview.stackexchange.com. There is a lot of room for improvement in this code; CR is a good venue for learning how to improve it.

Here's an example of how a simple CA might look (this is something I was working on for fun a few weeks ago). It uses a bunch of `button` elements to display the grid, but notice how the display routine could easily be swapped out with a canvas or some other mechanism.

```js
//
// Cell
//

function Cell(grid, x, y) {
    /** @type Grid */
    this.grid = grid;
    /** @type number */
    this.x = x;
    /** @type number */
    this.y = y;
}

Cell.prototype.getAdjacent = function() {
    var cellX = this.x,
        cellY = this.y,
        grid = this.grid,
        result = [],
        cell;
    
    for (var y = cellY - 1; y <= cellY + 1; y++) {
        for (var x = cellX - 1; x <= cellX + 1; x++) {
            if (x == cellX && y == cellY) {
                continue;
            }
            cell = grid.getCell(x, y);
            cell && result.push(cell);
        }
    }
    return result;
};

//
// Grid
//

function Grid(width, height) {
    /** @type number */
    this.width = width;
    /** @type number */
    this.height = height;
    /** @type Array.<Cell> */
    this.cells = [];
    
    this.initCells();
}

Grid.prototype.initCells = function() {
    var width = this.width,
        height = this.height,
        cells = this.cells;
        
    for (var y = height; y--;) {
        for (var x = width; x--;) {
            cells.unshift(new Cell(this, x, y));
        }
    }
};

Grid.prototype.getCell = function(x, y) {
    var width = this.width,
        height = this.height,
        cells = this.cells;
        
    if (x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < width && y < height) {
        return cells[x + y * width];
    }
};

Grid.prototype.each = function(callback) {
    var cells = this.cells,
        cellCount = cells.length;
        
    for (var i = 0; i < cellCount; i++) {
        callback(cells[i], i);
    }
};


//
// GridDisplay
//

function GridDisplay(grid, element) {
    /** @type Grid */
    this.grid = grid;
    /** @type Element */
    this.element = element;
}

GridDisplay.prototype.drawCell = function(cell) {
    var display = this,
        button = document.createElement('button');
        
    button.style.border = '1px outset white';
    if (cell.value) {
        button.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    }
    button.onclick = function(event) {
        if (cell.value) {
            cell.value = false;
        } else {
            cell.value = true;
        }
        display.draw();
    };
    
    return button;
};

GridDisplay.prototype.draw = function() {
    var display = this,
        grid = this.grid,
        buttons = this.element.getElementsByTagName('button'),
        container;
        
    if (buttons.length) {
        grid.each(function(cell, i) {
            if (cell.value) {
                buttons[i].style.backgroundColor = 'black';
            } else {
                buttons[i].style.backgroundColor = null;
            }
        });
        return;
    }
    
    this.element.innerHTML = '';
    container = document.createElement('div');
    
    grid.each(function(cell, i) {
        if (!cell.x) {
            container.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
        }
        container.appendChild(display.drawCell(cell));
    });
    
    this.element.appendChild(container);
};


//
// Game
//

function Game(width, height, rule) {
    // The standard Game of Life is symbolised as "B3/S23": 
    // A cell is "Born" if it has exactly 3 neighbours, 
    // "Stays alive" if it has 2 or 3 living neighbours.
    var bornSurvive = rule.match(/\d+/g);
    
    this.birthRule = bornSurvive[0];
    this.survivalRule = bornSurvive[1];
    this.grid = new Grid(width, height);
    this.gridDisplay = new GridDisplay(this.grid, board);
    this.gridDisplay.draw();
}

Game.prototype.tick = function() {
    var grid = this.grid,
        survivalRule = this.survivalRule,
        birthRule = this.birthRule;
    
    grid.each(function(cell, i) {
        var neighbors = cell.getAdjacent();
        var liveNeighborCount = 0;
        
        for (var j = 0; j < neighbors.length; j++) {
            if (neighbors[j].value) {
                ++liveNeighborCount;
            }
        }
        if (cell.value) {
            cell.nextValue = ~survivalRule.indexOf(liveNeighborCount);
        } else {
            cell.nextValue = ~birthRule.indexOf(liveNeighborCount);
        }
    });
    grid.each(function(cell) {
        cell.value = cell.nextValue;
    });
    this.gridDisplay.draw();
};


function createButton(label, callback) {
    var button = document.createElement('input');
    button.type = 'button';
    button.value = label;
    button.onclick = callback;
    document.body.appendChild(button);
}

var board = document.getElementById('board');
var game;
var interval;

createButton('new game', function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    board.innerHTML = '';
    game = new Game(50, 50, prompt('Enter a rule', 'B3/S23'));
});

createButton('randomize', function() {
    var cells = game.grid.cells;
    clearInterval(interval);
    for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        cells[i].value = Math.random() * 2 | 0;
    }
    game.gridDisplay.draw();
});

createButton('step', function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    game.tick();
});

createButton('go', function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setInterval(function () {
        game.tick()
    }, 100);
});

createButton('stop', function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
});
```

```css
body { font: 10pt sans-serif; }
div { font-size: 1px; }
button { width: 8px; height: 8px; margin:0; padding: 0; vertical-align: middle; }
```

```html
<div id="board"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's quite an interesting idea using `<div>`s for this :)

Usually I really like SVG for graphics on the web, but this is a fine example where the `<canvas>` element just makes sense, I mean you basically work with pixels anyway.

So if you want to keep the `<div>`s follow Cerbrus' advice and get rid of `hasClass()` or at least try the native `el.classList.contains()`. That should be a lot quicker according to [this jsperf](http://jsperf.com/pure-js-hasclass-vs-jquery-hasclass/28).
But it's always best to have it in a variable right in JS.

Just as a teaser, check out this canvas game of life: 
http://pmav.eu/stuff/javascript-game-of-life-v3.1.1/